# Laravel 5.4 post redirect to GET status 302

Tags: php, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I have a simple post form in Laravel that's is being redirecting to the same form after the post (with status 302). I'm not sure if it's any route problem or something different.

my form:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'subscription.store']) !!}
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_xxxxxx"
data-amount="2000"
data-name="Name"
data-description="2 widgets"
data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
data-locale="auto"
data-currency="cad">
</script>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Route:
    `Route::post('/subscription/store', 'Admin\SubscriptionController@store')->name('subscription.store')->middleware('can:admin-access');`

Cntroller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
    $user = User::find($request->user()->id);
    $user->newSubscription('main', 'main')->create($request->input('stripeToken'));

    if ($user->subscribed('main')) {
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
    }
    }
```

Chrome network log:

`Request Method:POST
    Status Code:302 Found
    Remote Address:10.1.1.33:80
    Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade`

Any suggestions what's missing or wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a default redirection. Currently you only redirect when the user is subscribed. Set a default route to redirect in case if they aren't.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find($request->user()->id);
    $user->newSubscription('main', 'main')->create($request->input('stripeToken'));

    if ($user->subscribed('main')) {
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
    }

    return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. I have a middleware that's responsible to check the subscription status in every request and I had by mistake enabled in my constructor.